# CMake project with testing

Tags: c++, testing, makefile, cmake, ctest

I'm making a project with cmake and I want to add tests. This is my first time using cmake, so I'm kinda walking in the dark. Does anyone have any examples on how to start this procedure, or an open source project I could look at?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this lines to your CMakeLists.txt

```
enable_testing()
add_executable(exec_name exec_source_file)
add_test(test_name exec_name)
```

Comment: This should help me get going. Thx!